# Implemented Facebook login in a website

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, facebook, facebook-login

I have a web app which works on the server side with PHP and MySql and on the client side with Javascript / JQuery.
I implemented the login button provided on developers.facebook since I have an App Key.
I'd like to allow users to sign up using Facebook, so I think I should retrieve an Access Key provided by Facebook, store it in my database and then use it to allow the user to log in.

- After the user has allowed my app using the login button, how can I retrieve an access key?
- Is this possible or not?  Can I store it to allow the user to log in again?
- Do I have permission to request both the user's name and surname?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Each of these questions can be answered by looking at the API _documentation_ that Facebook provides.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the name, surname, birthday, latest wall-post.. well to keep it short you can allow and show everything of the person, as they can click on the Accept or Refuse button where they will be redirected if you add an log-in/register button.
As for the SQL Access key, I do know that you can store them, only thing is that i don't know any code :( , but it is possible.

I hope that some other users know how the access key script works.